# JavaScript Input Validation First Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and working on a small project. One of the last requirements I can not work out how to do is to do with validation on a text box.

I want to be able to select a text input field and check that the entered information starts with a 0 or it sends an alert informing the user that the entry needs to start with a 0.

This is my input

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txbPhoneNumber" Runat="server" onkeypress="return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||(event||window.event).which)));" MaxLength="11"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Not sure if/how this is possible in JS, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It would look nicer to use a javascript `functon`

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txbPhoneNumber" Runat="server" onkeypress="validate()" MaxLength="11"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

`this` should return you element that has raised the function.

```
function validate() {
 if(this.value.lastIndexOf('0') === 0)
 { 
   alert('Does not start with 0');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expressions. You could try the `onchange` event:

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txbPhoneNumber" Runat="server" onchange="if (this.value.indexOf('0') != 0) alert('Input does not start with 0!);" MaxLength="11"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
if($("txbPhoneNumber").val().substr(0, 1) == "0"){
    //do something
}else{
    alert("start with 0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified from w3schools;

```
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x[0] != '0') {
        alert("First char must be zero");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```